# Javascript create array of objects of length n

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there a one-liner to create an array of objects of length `n`?

```
const arr = [
    { first_name: '', last_name: '' },
    { first_name: '', last_name: '' },
    { first_name: '', last_name: '' },
]
```

I've tried below but am getting `SyntaxError: unexpected token: ':'`

```
const arr = [...Array(3).map(x => { first_name: '', last_name: '' })]
```

Comment: not to be smart, but you could minify your code to one line. for loops work good too.

Comment: Map not working with empty array, b/c Array(3) set only length, but no elements there. To make map work you should fill your array first `const arr = [...Array(3).fill(1).map(...`

Comment: Try this   `Array.from({length:3}).map(x => ({first_name: '', last_name: ''}))`

Comment: @JuliaShestakova yes, but then the spread syntax is pointless. Typically it's one or the other, e.g., `[...Array(n)].map(() => ({}))` or `Array(n).fill().map(() => ({}))`. I don't recommend `fill` though--more typing and prone to aliasing bugs.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to wrap return value by `()` whenever you want to return object from arrow function you need to wrap `()` else it will treat it as start of function body,

```js
console.log([...Array(3).map(x => ({ first_name: '', last_name: '' }))])
```

Now you see error is gone but why the values are undefined ? because map doesn't loop over the empty slots you need to use fill

```js
console.log([...Array(3).fill(0).map(x => ({ first_name: '', last_name: '' }))])
```

Or you can use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

```js
let arr = Array.from({ length: 3 } , () => ({ first_name: '', last_name: '' }))

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: In version 2, what's the point of the spread syntax? I'd use either `fill` or spread, but not both.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to wrap returned object in `()` but you can also use `Array.from` method instad.

```js
const array = Array.from(Array(3), () => ({ first_name: '', last_name: '' }))
console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is seen not as an object, you need to wrap the object in `()` and you need to use fill() for map to work.

```
const arr = [...Array(3).fill().map(x => ({ first_name: '', last_name: '' }))]
```

Comment: You should explain *why* you need to use `fill()`.